# call an external API in an Ethereum project

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I read this article https://medium.com/decentlabs/building-your-first-ethereum-oracle-1ab4cccf0b31 and I want to make a web request to know the temperature as explained. however I have learned that request-promise-native is deprecated. How can I replace it? Can anyone give me an example?
I don't have to use oraclize

Answer (score 0):

In order to call external APIs in contract, you have to use oraclize service.

Sample code for your reference....

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
import "./usingOraclize.sol";  //Importing Oraclize
contract TestOraclizeCall is usingOraclize {
       uint public price;
       event Log(string text);
       //Constructor
       function TestOraclizeCall() {
             OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0x5049063e4a7704ac155e4f1f42a4954bbef5bbde);
       }
       function __callback(bytes32 _myid, string _result) {
             require (msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
             Log(_result);
             price = parseInt(_result, 2);
       }
       function update() payable {
            oraclize_query("URL","json(https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD).USD");
       }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but for my project I don't have to use Oraclize but implement a contract that plays the role of oracle. so i have my contract and the oracle contract which fetches data from the outside via an oracle service.